# Looking for an efficient way to display PDFs

Tags: software-rec, configuration, pdf

I've used several unix tools to display PDFs, like `xpdf`, `evince`, `epdfview`…

What I'm looking for is not very complicated.
I'd like to display a full page inside the application window with **reduced margins** (no margins or very small margins) and be able to go to the **next/previous page** by simply pressing one button.

I don't know any PDF viewer which can be configured to do that. Does anyone know how it could be done?

Comment: Did you consider writing a minimal app using `poppler` library (optionally with Python or Ruby bindings)?

Comment: I'll be considering it if there is no answer to this question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I much enjoy using [`mupdf`](http://www.mupdf.com/).  There's no visible UI and the [default keybindings are fine.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/mupdf.1.html)

Comment: I just tried it, but if I change the view, it is not preserved when I change the page :-(. However it looks minimal and nice, and maybe I'll try to hack this one if there is no other one that allows to do what I want.

Comment: Really?  When I for example zoom in (`+`) and go to the next page or down (using the cursor keys) or to page 10 (`10g`), everything stays zoomed.

Comment: No, the vertical centering is changed :-/

Comment: Weird, this doesn't happen here, using the left and right arrow to change pages doesn't change the view.  (You could try resizing the window; using `xmonad` here, `mupdf` misbehaves until I do this (doesn't know its window's size))

Comment: Ah right! pagedown and right are not the same, sorry. I was confused by the manual which does not distinguish them. So, this solves my problem, thank you! Now I need to find a way to add reverse video and map mouse wheel to left/right… :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try out **[MuPDF](http://mupdf.com/)**, **[gsviev](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/)** and **[apvlv](http://naihe2010.github.com/apvlv/)**.

Oh, and **[llpp](http://repo.or.cz/w/llpp.git)** maybe.

Comment: Tried `mupdf` and `apvlv` but they both change the view when I go to the next page, the top margin is displayed again :-/